# Paragraph first child text formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing a problem to change the format of the first paragraph when I remove the parent div class and put it in main container class.

The class name is `'inside-content'` when I put it along with the container then it doesn't work but when I apply it to the immediate parent class then it works.

My code:

```
<div class="container">

<h1> Sample Text</h1>

    <div class="inside-content">
        <p>Our 2011 collection, along with our fully updated range of contract furniture brochures are available to download. For your copy, please click the links shown on the left.</p>
        <p>Our 2011 collection, along with our fully updated rtange of contract furniture brochures are available to download. For your copy, please click the links shown on the left.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container inside-content">

<h1> Sample Text</h1>

    <p>Our 2011 collection, along with our fully updated range of contract furniture brochures are available to download. For your copy, please click the links shown on the left.</p>
    <p>Our 2011 collection, along with our fully updated rtange of contract furniture brochures are available to download. For your copy, please click the links shown on the left.</p>
</div>
```

The output is here : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/cckwL8s8/1/)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cckwL8s8/3/ is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Exactly like that. Thanks Sunil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [:first-of-type pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) instead of *:first-child*:

```
.inside-content p:first-of-type {
  /* your style here */
}
```